# How to increase the size of an iterator in a for-loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, iterator, iteration

I have a very simple `for` loop that iterates over each of the 100 elements of a character vector called `doc`.

Maybe something like:

```
for (i in seq_along(doc)){
  ytime <- proc.time()
  mycorpus<- VCorpus(VectorSource(doc[i]))
  ... some other functions ...
  print(proc.time() - ytime)
}
```

Instead of iterating over each single element, is it possible to let `i` be chunks of (say) ten elements of `doc`?

Such that it only takes 10 iterations to sequence along `doc` and ten elements of `doc` are fed to VCorpus at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hard code it  like

```
n=10
for (i in seq_len(length(doc)/n)){
ytime <- proc.time()
  mycorpus<- VCorpus(VectorSource(doc[(n*(i-1)+1):(n*i)]))
  ... some other functions ...
  print(proc.time() - ytime)
}
```